# Extract string from html files

Tags: string, awk, extract

I have many html files. each file contain the follwing line :

```
<img src="<BASE_HTTP_URL>bladf.gif" border="0" alt="" />
```

I need to extract first the html file name, and then the file name after BASE_HTTP_URL. in this case it is bladf.gif it can be any file name and many kind of extentions.

I have tried to extract the name of the file by using this awk :

```
for f in *.html
do
awk -F'"' '/img src=/{print $4}' $f
done
```

but i get zero as a result. how can i print the file name and next to it the file name next to `BASE_HTTP_URL`?

thanks

Comment: Post your expected output as it's very unclear what `the file name and next to it the file name next to BASE_HTTP_URL` means.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'"' '/img src=/{match($2, "(.*/)(.*)", url); print $2, url[1], url[2]}'
```

if I correctly understand your need.

Here's the sample output:

```
alex@rhyme ~ $ echo '<img src="http://some/url/bladf.gif" border="0" alt="" />' | awk -F'"' '/img src=/{match($2, "(.*/)(.*)", url); print $2, url[1], url[2];}'
http://some/url/bladf.gif http://some/url/ bladf.gif
alex@rhyme ~ $ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.0.2
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation.
```

What is your awk version?

Comment: The 3rd arg for match() is gawk-specific so other awks would produce thatsyntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this:

```
$ cat file1.html
foo
<img src="<BASE_HTTP_URL>bladf.gif" border="0" alt="" />
bar

$ cat file2.html
foo
<img src="<BASE_HTTP_URL>whatever.gif" border="0" alt="" />
bar

$ awk -F'"' '/img src=/{print FILENAME, $2}' *.html
file1.html <BASE_HTTP_URL>bladf.gif
file2.html <BASE_HTTP_URL>whatever.gif
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'"' 'sub(/<img src="<BASE_HTTP_URL>/,""){print FILENAME, $1}' *.html
file1.html bladf.gif
file2.html whatever.gif
```

If none of that is what you wanted, update your question to clarify.